# What is the fundamental group of a punctured cylinder?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be the standard open cylinder (say, the quotient of $\mathbb{C}$ by the action of $z\mapsto z+1$). Let $X^*$ be $X$ with a point removed.

What is $\pi_1(X^*)$?

It's $F_2$ right? (the free group on two generators?) Does it being "open" change things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is $\mathbb F_2$.
This can be proved by noticing that it is homotopy equivalent to the wedge of two circles.
The idea is that you can make the hole larger, and then shrink everything else to be 1 dimensional. This yields a circle, and a line whose both ends are glued to the circle. Now slide the two ends to the same place on the circle, and you are done.
This process can be implemented as deformation retract which induces a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: So, that's what I was thinking, though it doesn't actually deformation retract onto the wedge of two circles, since the cylinder is open right?

Comment: I can't see why wouldn't it be an actual deformation retraction.